# C# deserialize to dynamic class

Tags: c#, json

On my home automation system, to create a plugin with documentation I must use class with summary.

My plugin talk to my xiaomi gateway to get informations about sensors. So there are different type of sensor like "sensor_ht", "magnet" or "motion".

For each sensor, there are common proprieties and a data part that is different. I get status of each sensor in jon.

For example :

```
{"cmd":"report","model":"magnet","sid":"","short_id":40805,"data":"
{\"status\":\"close\"}"}
{"cmd":"report","model":"sensor_ht","sid":"","short_id":40805,"data":"
{\"voltage\":\"3000\",\"temperature\":\"2367\",\"humidity,\":\"5285\"}"}
```

So I create many class like this, each sensor is in a single file.

sensor_ht.cs :

```
public class sensor_ht
{
    public string model { get; set; } = "sensor_ht";
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public string battery_type { get; set; } = "CR2032";
    public int battery { get; set; }
    public sensor_ht.Report report { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public int voltage { get; set; }
    public string temperature { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
}
```

magnet.cs :

```
public class magnet
{
    public string model { get; set; } = "sensor_ht";
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public string battery_type { get; set; } = "CR2032";
    public int battery { get; set; }
    public magnet.Report report { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public int voltage { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my report class :

```
public class Report
{

        public string cmd { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string sid { get; set; }
        public int short_id { get; set; }
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
}
```

After deserialize the report, I initialize the instance with :

```
dynamic d = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("XiaomiSmartHome.Equipement." + read.model);
```

But to create the data part I deserialize the data of the report with :

```
dynamic data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(read.data);
```

I want this data to be the right Report class. I tried :

```
d.report = data2;
```

But it sais that it's impossible to convert Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to XiaomiSmartHome.Equipement.Report

So my way to handle this is right ? And how to deserialize the data part to the right report ?

Thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer, I use :

```
var messageType = Type.GetType(deserialized.MessageType);
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
Convert.ToString(deserialized.Message), messageType);
```